# wp_dropdown_users array for param selected

Tags: dropdown

The `wp_dropdown_users` has the param:

> 'multi' (bool|int) Whether to skip the ID attribute on the 'select'
>   element. Accepts 1|true or 0|false. Default 0|false.

But the param `selected` only allow a unique id.

> 'selected'
>
> (int) Which user ID should be selected. Default 0.

How is it possible?

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: My understanding of 'multi' is that if you want to display the user dropdown more than once on the same page, then we don't want an id on the HTML markup. That is not related to having a multiple options selected by default for each dropdown. The dropdown only supports a single default value, as far as I understand.

Comment: mmm ok, I have changed my users.php to allow a new param expecting an array instead of one id to set the selecteds items. But could be great that the default "selected" param allows int or array of ints

Comment: There's the `wp_dropdown_users` filter, maybe that could help with adjustments?